# Distribute executable with python pip

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface, setuptools

I am trying to distribute a CLI tool for public use. My code contains a executable (written in golang) and a helper python script (used by the executable).

My initial approach was to call the executable from python using this, where main is the entrypoint of the cli command.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def main():
    dst = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/golangexec'
    arg_list = [dst,"myclitool"]
    cmd_args = sys.argv[1:]
    args = arg_list + cmd_args
    subprocess.call(args)
    return
```

`

My package is this

```
project   

│   setup.py    
│   
└───myclitool
│   │   golangexec
│   │   __init__.py
|   |   pyhelper.py
|   |   run.py
```

With `setup.py` being:

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(

name='mypkg',
packages=['myclitool'],
version='0.1',
entry_points='''
    [console_scripts]
    mycli=myclitool.run:main
'''
)
```

However, this doesn't install my executable at the same location with the rest of the files.

I have tried to place everything inside package data, but then I face permission denied error when running exe using subprocess.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bundling the executable via `package_data` is the right approach. I'd rather find out why the permission error is raised - do you miss the executable bit on the `golangexec` file when installed?

Comment: Well, `package_data` is **data**, not executables, right? For executables `setuptools` have `scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pythonic solution, but for anyone struggling having the same problem, npm allows a `bin` param in the `package.json` file, where you can directly link up your executable.

```
{
  "name": "myclipkg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": {
    "myclitool": "./golangexec"
   },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/myclipkg/cli#README"
}
```